# Apex 5.1: Questions on Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

Our users have requested some additional functionality in interactive grids, which to my knowledge, it does not seem available out of the box, or we might need additional plugins or I'm missing something. Please advise:

1. Can I disable the users from resizing column widths, that is, they cannot increase or decrease the column widths?
2. Enable Complex Filters to the users, such as, make a search for particular words in a column. For example look for word 'Joe' OR 'Peter' OR 'Mary' in a particular column.
3. Prompt the user with a message for confirmation when deleting a row.

I looked at the new version of APEX (18.1) but it does not mention any of these functionalities. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 1. is unusual: users asking to **not** be able to do something! 2. There is the option to test values `in` a list `Joe; Peter; Mary` but I guess you mean embedded within other text in the column value. 3. Don't see why they need this as (a) the record isn't really deleted until they press Save, just "struck through", and (b) there is a `revert changes` option on the row menu if they delete by mistake.

Comment: 1. Users can be really picky 2. Yeah value is embedded within a sentence of text. This kind of filter is available in Excel, so users expect something similar in interactive grids. 3. I agree it should be enough so I will try to convince them.